# OpenGL - Texture not displaying properly (clamping?)

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I've just started learning about textures in OpenGL and have come across this problem :

Suspected : Problem with function `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` or `glVertexAttribPointer()`

For the VertexBuffer and IndexBuffer Constructors they take in the size, data and indices,data respectively

// Cant post images, dont have enough reputation (sry)

Texture.cpp

```
Texture::Texture(const std::string & filepath)
    : m_RendererID(0), m_Filepath(filepath), m_ImageBuffer(nullptr), 
    m_Width(0), m_Height(0), m_BPP(0)
{
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
m_ImageBuffer = stbi_load(filepath.c_str(), &m_Width, &m_Height, &m_BPP, 4);

if (m_ImageBuffer == NULL)
    std::cout << "Unable to open file : " << m_Filepath << "!";

glGenTextures(1, &m_RendererID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_ImageBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

if (m_ImageBuffer)
    stbi_image_free(m_ImageBuffer);
}
```

main.cpp

```
float positions[] =
{
    // positions //texCoords
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};

unsigned int indices[] =
{
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

VertexBuffer vb(4 * 4 * sizeof(float), positions);

IndexBuffer ib(6, indices);

Shader shader("res/shaders/basic.shader");
shader.Bind();
shader.SetUniform4f("u_Color", 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

Texture texture("res/textures/pepe.jpg");
texture.Bind();
shader.SetUniform1i("u_Texture", 0);

Renderer renderer;

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), 0);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    renderer.Clear();

    renderer.Draw(ib, shader);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is the offset of the first component of the first generic vertex attribute in the array. This parameter is not set correctly for the texture coordinates:

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(float), 0);`</s>
`glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(float), (void*)(2*sizeof(float)));`

see [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 10.3.9 Vertex Arrays in Buffer Objects; page 409](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf)

> ... When an array is sourced from a buffer object for a vertex attribute, [...] the offset set for the vertex buffer [...] is used as the **offset in basic machine units** of the first element in that buffer’s data store.

---

Further the texture coordinates are confused. Change it to:

```
float positions[] =
{
    // positions //texCoords
    0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
   -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
   -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks a little 'better' now, however the texture looks as though it is being mirrored over the two triangles.

Comment: @XtraTerrestrialCoder Change the texture coordinates. See the extension to the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. If you wouldn't mind, could you tell me what was wrong with my coordinates. Thanks

Comment: @XtraTerrestrialCoder The u coordinates of the 1st and 2nd vertex attribute were swapped.